# what causes the data power object to goto pending state and how can it be resolved?

Tags: ibm-datapower, operationalerror

In datapower, the operational state of queue manager object is pending. The information provided for this operational state is as follows : "This message indicates that the configuration of the object has changed, but has not been committed and has yet to take effect. No user intervention is required." What is exactly causing this problem and how can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is "pending" for a MQ QM object it means that DataPower is trying to figure out if it has a connection to it or not.
Normally if a QM object is in "pending" for a while, more than 20 seconds, it would mean that it didn't get the connection.
Check the System log and you'll probably see a ton of connection errors to the QM server.

First go to Troubleshooting from the Control Panel and do a TCP test to make sure you have a connection to the MQ server using the IP and port of the listener on the QM.
If you get a connection then check the MQ logs for any authentication issues, eg. user and/or auth-records. You need a Server-Connection channel for DataPower!

If you don't get a connection in TCP test then check your firewalls and also make sure that the DataPower network is setup correctly if you have multiple network cards (NIC) setup and set a static route for the MQ on the correct NIC.